# How to create a dynamic dialog in JSF1?

Tags: jsf

i want to create a dynamic dialog in **JSF1.1**, and i was wondering what's the easiest JSF library that can help me to accomplish that.

please advise, thanks.

Comment: check this link http://livedemo.exadel.com/richfaces-demo/richfaces/modalPanel.jsf

Comment: You could also use a JavaScript library to handle the task.

Comment: @skuntsel, like what ? please advise, and keep in mind that i want to create a dynamic dialog not just a dialog.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**JSF 1.1**

You can use the component `rich:modalPanel` from the RichFaces components library.

According to [this](http://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/latest_3_3_X/en/migrationguide/html/RichFacesMigrationIssues31to32.html) :

> **4.2.6.1. Description**
>   Since we've migrated to the JSF 1.2 standard in RichFaces 3.2.0 [...]

The RichFaces latest version to support JSF 1.1 is RichFaces 3.1.6 that you can download [here](http://www.jboss.org/richfaces/download/archive.html).

PrimeFaces 0.X is supposed to support JSF 1.1 but can't find any download link.

**JSF 1.2**

In JSF 1.2 you have one more choice :

1. [RichFaces 3.3.3](http://livedemo.exadel.com/richfaces-demo/richfaces/modalPanel.jsf?c=modalPanel&tab=usage) will be available [here](http://www.jboss.org/richfaces/download/stable.html). (component `rich:modalPanel`)
2. [PrimeFaces 1.1](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/dialogHome.jsf) will be available [here](http://repository.primefaces.org/org/primefaces/primefaces/1.1/). (component `p:dialog`)

Both are the latest versions of each librabries to support JSF 1.2.

Comment: are you sure that they are compitable with jsf 1.1 not jsf 1.2

Comment: @MahmoudSaleh my brain interpreted 1.2 while reading 1.1, updated the answer!

Comment: any ideas if PrimeFaces 1.1 or RichFaces 3.3.3 supports dynamic dialog ? and where can i find showcases for them, because the primefaces showcase link is for latest version.

Comment: For RichFaces : http://livedemo.exadel.com/richfaces-demo/richfaces/modalPanel.jsf

Comment: I hope you have a good reason to get stuck on JSF 1.1 since JSF 2.X have major improvements and 1.1 is no more supported.

Comment: @MahmoudSaleh I'm so sorry for you! :)

Comment: last question, can i create dynamic dialog with primefaces 1 or just a static dialog

Comment: i had issues running primefaces on websphere so i used an alternative solution for the sake of time, but thanks a lot for continuous support and the willing to help.